# JQuery.Post() purpose and difference

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

While working on a website I had a content area division whose content I wanted to update according to the image I click on. Now, I had a customized scrollbar which I used in the content area. Now at first I wrote the following snippet for onclick script function :

```
function xyz(){
    $("#content-area").load("abc.php");
    $("#content-area").mCustomScrollbar({scrollButtons:{enable:true}});
}
```

But the second line of the script wasn't responding i.e, I wasnt getting the scrollbar. Instead when I used this piece of code snippet it worked :

```
$.post("abc.php", function(data){
   $("#content-area").html(data);
   $("#content-area").mCustomScrollbar({scrollButtons:{enable:true}});
});
```

I am wondering the function of the $.post() and why the first snippet didnt work while the second snippet worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case that `mCustomScrollbar` will be executed right after the AJAX request is *sent*: remember, first `A` in AJAX is for `asynchronous`. But it obviously has nothing to work on yet, as *response* from server is not here yet.

In the second snippet `mCustomScrollbar` widget creation happens right after the AJAX request's response is *received* (as this line is part of `$.post` success handler now) *and* that `#content-area` is filled with necessary structure (with `.html()`) call. So now it works correctly.

You can use the fact that `$.load` method can be supplied with custom callback function that will be executed when the request completes, as described [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/load/). For example:

```
$("#content-area").load("abc.php", function() {
     $(this).mCustomScrollbar({scrollButtons:{enable:true}});
});
```

Note `$(this)` usage: as `this` is set to each DOM element in turn inside that callback function, you don't need to walk over the DOM looking for that `content-area` yet again; it's enough just to wrap that element into jQuery object.

Comment: yeah I know the purpose of this keyword. thanx a lot...:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use callback function which is executed when request is complete:

```
$("#content-area").load("abc.php", function(){
     $(this).mCustomScrollbar({scrollButtons:{enable:true}});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in the first example the second statement was being executed before the completion of the `.load()` function. In the second you are correctly using the success function, which is only executed after the completion of the POST request.